# SQL search not running

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

Hi guys i have the following search command

```
public List<User> advancedSearch(String searchString, String criteria, String ordering) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE u.username LIKE :search ORDER BY u.username, order");
    q.setParameter("search", "%" + searchString + "%");
    q.setParameter("order", "%" + ordering + "%");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

i get the values of the searhString, criteria and ordering from the U.I, the aim is to produce a query that is fully customisable, however currently i am having issues with the ordering, how can i use the value from the U.I. (order) in the query, as currently it is not running like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you mixed between the column and the table with big letter U

you should use this

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE U.username LIKE :search ORDER BY U.username");
```

`U.username`   and not `u.username`

**EDIT:**

```
  Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE u.username LIKE :search ORDER BY u.username " + ordering + ");
```

and remove that line

```
  q.setParameter("order", "%" + ordering + "%");
```

you cant set DESC and ASC as parameters

Comment: thanks i have tried that and i get the error `Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE U.username LIKE :search ORDER BY U.username, U:order]. 
[73, 80] The identification variable 'U:order' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.`

Comment: that works fine but i am now unable to change the order to be asc or desc

Comment: what about if you add asc or desc in the end of the query like that:`ORDER BY U.username DESC`

Comment: well :) nice it helped you . make sure to mark my answer as solved. good luck

Comment: Sorry i ment it only works if i state it to be ASC or DESC i can not set this using input from the U.I.